# save javaDoc to .tex in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, latex, javadoc

Is there any method to export the javaDoc from eclipse into a .tex file? I know that I can export it into a html. But TeX is smarter for our project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at my [ltxdoclet](https://github.com/ePaul/ltxdoclet), which can produce LaTeX source from the Javadoc (and optionally even includes a formatted version of the source code).

Answer (score 2):

I did not try it, but I found this Javadoc taglet for LaTeX on the web: http://users.informatik.uni-halle.de/~grau/LaTeXlet/index.html

In the Javadoc export wizard there is an option to select a custom taglet, there you can try to apply this.